# How would one go about gathering information from one column in an SQL database(specific cell) that has double or triple values

Tags: html, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

How would one go about gathering information from one column in an SQL database(specific cell)
that has double or triple values stored in it, like:

row_number    column1
1             A,B
2             B,D
*Note: the above table is not true, just an example

and place it in a column with the "AS" attribute according to a rank over to another column
after you have split column1?

The situation I have is as follows:

I am able to split and do the above with case statements, but I am only able to get value "B" after I split it and placed it in the AS Score column according to the rank over of column called ElIndex.
Code as follows:

```
SQLStr1 = "DECLARE @ScoreA VARCHAR(100), @ScoreB VARCHAR(100), @ScoreC VARCHAR (100), @ScoreD VARCHAR (100), @ScoreE VARCHAR (100), @ScoreF VARCHAR (100), @ScoreG VARCHAR (100) SET @ScoreA = 1 SET @ScoreB = 2 SET @ScoreC = 3 SET @ScoreD = 4 SET @ScoreE = 5 SET @ScoreF = 6 SET @ScoreG = 7"
            SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " SELECT DISTINCT cs.ModuleName, cs.ScreenName, se.AnswerScore, cs.CourseName, tf.FileText, tf.VoiceFile, se.ElIndex"
            if rsUserModules1("LinkType") = "Submit Answer Multi" then
            readyList = Split(rsUserModules1("LinkAction"),",")

        For i = 0 TO UBound(readyList) -1
            if readyList(i) = "A" then
                SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " ,(CASE WHEN se.LinkAction = 'A' THEN @ScoreA "
                SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " WHEN @ScoreA = RANK()OVER(ORDER BY se.ElIndex) THEN '-1' ELSE '0' END) AS Score"
            end if
            if readyList(i) = "B" then
                SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " ,(CASE WHEN se.LinkAction = 'B' THEN @ScoreB"
                SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " WHEN @ScoreB = RANK()OVER(ORDER BY se.ElIndex) THEN '-1' ELSE '0' END) AS Score"
            end if
            if readyList(i) = "C"  then
                SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " ,(CASE WHEN se.LinkAction = 'C' THEN @ScoreC" 
                SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " WHEN @ScoreC = RANK()OVER(ORDER BY se.ElIndex) THEN '-1' ELSE '0' END) AS Score" 
            end if
            if readyList(i) = "D"  then
                SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " ,(CASE WHEN se.LinkAction = 'D' THEN @ScoreD" 
                SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " WHEN @ScoreD = RANK()OVER(ORDER BY se.ElIndex) THEN '-1' ELSE '0' END) AS Score"
            end if
            if readyList(i) = "E" then
                SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " ,(CASE WHEN se.LinkAction = 'E' THEN @ScoreE" 
                SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " WHEN @ScoreE = RANK()OVER(ORDER BY se.ElIndex) THEN '-1' ELSE '0' END) AS Score"
            end if      
        next

        end if

        SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " FROM GroupScreens cs WITH (NOLOCK)"
        SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " INNER JOIN TextFiles tf WITH (NOLOCK)"
        SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " ON cs.ScreenName = tf.ScreenName"
        SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " INNER JOIN Screens s WITH (NOLOCK)"
        SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " ON s.ScreenName = tf.ScreenName"

        SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " INNER JOIN ScreenElements se WITH (NOLOCK)"
        SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " ON se.CourseName = cs.CourseName  AND tf.SEUID = se.UID"

        SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " WHERE tf.CourseName= '" & Name1 & "' AND cs.ModuleName= '" & Name & "' AND (s.ScreenType = 'A' AND ( [FileText] NOT LIKE '%?%'  AND [FileText] NOT LIKE '%...%' AND [FileText] NOT LIKE '%True or False%' AND [FileText] NOT LIKE '%Name%' AND [FileText] NOT LIKE '%There may be%' AND [FileText] NOT LIKE '%Select%' AND [FileText] NOT LIKE '%[(]%' AND [FileText] NOT LIKE ''))AND cs.ScreenName ='" & ScreenName1 &  "'"
        SQLStr1 = SQLStr1 & " ORDER BY se.ElIndex"
```

The problem I am having is in the image below:
[image: The problem I am having]

Comment: Can you provide table and data. The description does not help much.

Comment: I gather a lot of information from 4 different tables, that will difficult to do.

Comment: Sorry, I will try now, just very busy.

Comment: I did add an image to the question, if you right click and open in new tab you will see, not sure if it is what you are looking for, but it is the result of the above code.